# How to get the full URL of a Drupal page?

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system

I need to be grabbing the URL of the current page in a Drupal site. It doesn't matter what content type it is - can be any type of node.

I am NOT looking for the path to theme, or the base url, or Drupal's get_destination. I'm looking for a function or variable that will give me the following in full:

http://example.com/node/number

Either with or without (more likely) the `http://`.

Comment: drupal_get_destination is the solution since you know the domain name and if you are coding for the same domain, you can use it!

Comment: Related: [How do I get the full URL of the current page?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/27880/1908) at Drupal SE

Answer (score 53):

[drupal_get_destination()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_get_destination/6) has some internal code that points at the correct place to getthe current internal path. To translate that path into an absolute URL, the [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/url/6) function should do the trick. If the 'absolute' option is passed in it will generate the full URL, not just the internal path. It will also swap in any path aliases for the current path as well.

```
$path = isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : '<front>';
$link = url($path, array('absolute' => TRUE));
```

Comment: according to your link, drupal_get_destination() returns "destination=/node/number" or, for /node/number?destination=bla, "destination=bla". passing this to url() doesn't seem to work to me.

Comment: Doh. You're correct. I've updated the snippet with the correct code. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, but I had to add:

    `$echo link;`

for a facebook app to work!

Thanks!

Answer (score 37):

This is what I found to be useful

```
global $base_root;
$base_root . request_uri();
```

Returns query strings and it's what's used in core: [page_set_cache()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/page_set_cache/6)

Comment: Note that this method won't work if your site is not at the domain root. For example, if your base URL is http://example.com/folder, this method will result in http://example.com/folder/folder/page.

Comment: If that is the case then there is a bug in core. see that the code comments in http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/conf_init/6 "Build $base_root (everything until first slash after "scheme://")."

Comment: Another thing that could be causing issues that you're seeing if if you're web server is passing the wrong values in for $_SERVER see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/request_uri/6.

Answer (score 19):

You can also do it this way:

```
$current_url = 'http://' .$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

It's a bit faster.

Comment: Always program to an interface not an implementation.

Answer (score 14):

Try the following:

```
url($_GET['q'], array('absolute' => true));
```

Comment: This is a little more drupaly: url(current_path(), array('absolute' => true));

Answer (score 12):

This method all is old method, in drupal 7 we can get it very simple

```
    current_path()
```

- http://example.com/node/306 returns "node/306".
- http://example.com/drupalfolder/node/306 returns "node/306" while base_path() returns "/drupalfolder/".
- http://example.com/path/alias (which is a path alias for node/306) returns "node/306" as opposed to the path alias.

and another function with tiny difference

```
request_path()
```

- http://example.com/node/306 returns "node/306".
- http://example.com/drupalfolder/node/306 returns "node/306" while base_path() returns "/drupalfolder/".
- http://example.com/path/alias (which is a path alias for node/306) returns "path/alias" as opposed to the internal path.
- http://example.com/index.php returns an empty string (meaning: front page).
- http://example.com/index.php?page=1 returns an empty string.

Comment: The question is about getting the *full* URL, i. e. something like `http://example.com/node/number` .

Answer (score 4):

I find using tokens pretty clean. 
It is integrated into core in Drupal 7.

```
<?php print token_replace('[current-page:url]'); ?>
```

Comment: Token `[site:current-page:path]` should work either.

Answer (score 3):

The following is more *Drupal-ish*:

```
url(current_path(), array('absolute' => true));
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Drupal 8** you can do this :

```
$url = 'YOUR_URL';
$url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUserInput('/' . $url,  array('absolute' => 'true'))->toString();
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe what you want is just plain old predefined variables.

Consider trying

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'']
```

Or read more [here](http://lv.php.net/reserved.variables).