# Drupal's Ubercart redirecting to a custom order complete/thank you page

Tags: php, drupal, ubercart

While using ubercart I need to insert some javascript tracking codes to the order complete/thank you page the user sees after checking out an order. Problem is, there is no .tpl file for this so I'd like to know if there's a way of redirecting users to a custom page I would like to build with all my js inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is, page.tpl.php is the output. You can add php to the bottom of the page with something like, if request_uri() == complete (or whatever your thank you page is), then print some js tracking code.

Refresh your theme/site cache and it should be good to go.

Comment: LOL! you won't believe that I just logged back to SO to write about a similar solution. This question inspired the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703426/how-to-get-the-full-url-of-a-drupal-page

Thanks a heap man.