# Get current page/url in a hook

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-7

In hook_css_alter, I want to disable style-sheets on specific pages. 
Was ok for the front page requirement with following snippet:

```
function morin_css_alter(&$css) {
  if(drupal_is_front_page()){
    foreach ($css as $data => $item) {
      unset($css[$data]);
    }
  }
}
```

Now  I need to remove specific styles on a photo-album page. I have thought of a few ways to do this, but I'd like to do it the drupal way.

The closest function I have found to do this is drupal_get_destination() ,
I don't think it's meant for this but it does return the current path in an array, as shown by the following snippet added in css_alter hook.

```
echo " PATH = " . var_dump(drupal_get_destination());

Output: PATH = array(1) { ["destination"]=> string(6) "photos" }
```

Is this the recommended way of getting the path from inside a function/hook,  or is there some variable in global namespace I should use instead?

Comment: See [this post...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703426/how-to-get-the-full-url-of-a-drupal-page) If Eaton says it, it IS the Drupal way in my book :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/request_path/7.

For Drupal 6, one has to use `$_GET['q']`.

Comment: drupal_get_destination() doest not always return the current path. The current path is actually the default value when no other destination (to be used in a redirect in case of, for instance, a successful form submit) has been provided. See the drupal_get_destination()'s documentation.

Comment: I said nothing about drupal_get_destination(), I assume you meant that as an additional information?

Comment: Yep, this is additional information as the original question mentioned using drupal_get_destination(). Sorry, I should have made it clearer.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the insight, just was I was looking for. drupal_get_destination did not feel right for this, now I see why.