# redirect users from desktop site to mobile site based on URL

Tags: php, mobile, drupal-6, redirect

I've got a mixed Drupal6 and php redirect question that I really need help with.

I've got a Drupal 6 site, with a smaller mobile site on a subdomain.
I'm building a custom module to redirect visitors of the site to the mobile site based on device and location (US users only).

I'm using mobile detect to discover the user's deviceL: https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect

and this answer to get my absolute URL on my drupal site: [How to get the full URL of a Drupal page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703426/how-to-get-the-full-url-of-a-drupal-page/703597#703597)

So far both pieces are working fine, but I'm not sure how to write the lines to go from one location to the next.
I've got about 8 specific urls that need to be redirected that would look something like this:

http://desktopsite.com/specific-page -> http://m.mobilesite.com/specific-page

I'm sure it's a basic PHP thing, but I'm stumped and could really use some guidance so I can move in the right direction. I've also tried contributed drupal modules, but because I have multi-languages sites I can't use them (they don't support the languages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are saying:

```
// Make a mobile detect object
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();
// Check the device
if($detect->isMobile()){
    // Here is where you put the page you have 
    // i.e. http://desktopsite.com/specific-page;
    $location = "http://desktopsite.com/specific-page;";
    // We need to swap the url in that $location variable
    $location = str_replace("http://desktopsite","http://m.mobilesite",$location);
    // Then to a classic redirect
    header("Location: {$location}");
}
```

Comment: That does look like the start of it. how would I use this as a base while handle 12-ish different URLS (Only 1 desktop site to 1 mobile site though, not multiple different sites)?

Comment: You mentioned that you already can get the absolute url of the page, so where I've put `$location = "http://desktopsite.com/specific-page"; ` you would put `$location = $absolute_url_you_got;` then the rest of the script will replace `"http://desktopsite"` at the start of the URL with `"http://m.mobilesite"` (I copied your example, the m.mobilesite might be a typo, perhaps it should be either 'm' or 'mobilesite' but not both).  Then the `header` part will redirect to that page.

Comment: So if you put that at the start of any page you want to redirect, with the change made to grab the absolute url of page you were on, it should just work.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, this did get me on the right track :)